# Your AdSense application status: Insufficient content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ads, adsense

After posting my adsense code onto my Ruby on Rails app I received this message:

> **Insufficient content**: To be approved for AdSense and show relevant ads on your site, your pages need to have enough text on them for our specialists to review and for our crawler to be able to determine what your pages are about.

[image]

The message also included these suggestions (which I think I meet with the possible exception of the 1st one and that's because it's an app not a blog):

> - Your content should contain complete sentences and paragraphs, not only headlines.
> - Ensure that your website is fully built and launched before you apply for AdSense - do not apply while your site’s still in a beta or
>     “under construction” phase or only consists of a website template.
> - Place the ad code on a live page of your website. It does not have to be the main page, but test pages that are empty except for the
>     AdSense ad code will not be approved.
> - Provide a clear navigation system for your visitors so that they can easily find all of the sections and pages of your website.

**application.html.erb**

```
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <p class="text-center">
      <%= yield :jumbotron %> <!-- this variable should be assigned in your controller action-->
      </p>
    </div>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <%= yield %> # includes pages/home (root route)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <% if current_user.present? %>
            <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %> # includes _recommendations
          <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**_recommendations.html.erb**

```
<div class="recommendations-padding">
    <div class="ad">
        <p>This is a test to see how the ads will fit here. This is a test to see how the ads will fit here. This is a test to see how the ads will fit here. This is a test to see how the ads will fit here. This is a test to see how the ads will fit here. This is a test to see how the ads will fit here. This is a test to see how the ads will fit here. This is a test to see how the ads will fit here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ad">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- Recommendation 1 -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-2458646218429910"
             data-ad-slot="6447006986"
             data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="ad">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- Recommendation #2 -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-2458646218429910"
             data-ad-slot="3293344589"
             data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="ad">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- Recommendation 3 -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:block"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-2458646218429910"
             data-ad-slot="9400473387"
             data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% if @user.habits.committed_for_today.any? %>
    <div class="page-header">
    <%= link_to habits_path(@habits) do %>
      <h1><b>Habits</b></h1>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="add-padding">
      <%= render partial: 'habits', locals: {habits: @habits} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if @user.valuations.any? %>
    <div class="page-header">
    <%= link_to valuations_path(@valuations) do %>
      <h1><b>Values</b></h1>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="add-padding">
      <%= render @valuations %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if @user.goals.any? %>
    <div class="page-header">
      <%= link_to goals_path(@goals) do %>
        <h1><b>Goals</b></h1>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="add-padding">
  <% if @user.goals.unaccomplished.any? %>
      <%= render @unaccomplished_goals %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @user.goals.accomplished.any? %>
    <div class="gold-standard">
      <%= render @accomplished_goals %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    </div>

  <% if @user.quantifieds.any? %>
    <div class="page-header">
    <%= link_to quantifieds_path(@quantifieds) do %>
      <h1><b>Stats</b></h1>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="add-padding">
  <% if @user.quantifieds.averaged.any? %>
    <h2><b>Averaged</b></h2>
      <%= render @averaged_quantifieds %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @user.quantifieds.instance.any? %>
    <h2><b>Instance</b></h2>
      <%= render @instance_quantifieds %>
  <% end %>
    </div>
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I can get approved about *Adsense*?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got approved to put up google ads via my blog. Once I got approved by google there they let you put ads on any site you own. Score!

Comment: Yes @MatiasCicero. Updated Answer. It was a round-about way. Good luck!

Comment: I changed the site name to http://www.livetochallenge.com/ if you want to take a look for yourself :) They are on the sidebar @MatiasCicero. I only have 2 ads. I think google limits you to 4 ads a page.